# polynomial terms in proc logistic and other regressions

Tags: sas

I'd like to do the following regression

```
proc logistic data=abc
    model y = x x*x x*x*x ....;
run;
```

Is there a shorthand to generate these polynomial terms? Thanks.

Comment: You might consider asking on stats.stackexchange.com - the responses to SAS questions are typically pretty meager here.

Comment: Also runsubmit.com may be worth a try as well.

Comment: @djacky Your code is the shorthand way.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:  That will teach me to look closer at the question before I answer.  The BAR operator is indeed for interaction - not polynomial effects.

Logistic does not have shorthand to accomplish this yet that I know of - but glimmix does have an experimental technique using the effect statement.  For example, this..

```
effect MyPoly = polynomial(x1-x3/degree=2);
       model y = MyPoly;
```

is the same as

```
model y = x1 x2 x3 x1*x1 x1*x2 x1*x3 x2*x2 x2*x3 x3*x3;
```

Comment: This generates interaction terms, not polynomial terms